# Unable to map servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am starting with servlets and I am trying to get 2 numbers from a form and add them using java logic but when running it is showing The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. So I am guessing it is mapping problem can someone help?

Here is my web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Addition</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>addNum</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>addLogic.sum</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>addNum</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[Also an image of project explorer for mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZizcZ.png)

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Also I see that you are using the maven folder structure, but I don't see a pom.xml, does your eclipse know how to package that project? Is it correctly deployed to the server?

Comment: No i am not using maven and i have a action="add" in my html form which I am mapping in url-pattern basically my html form looks like this ```<form action = "add" method= "post">
<input type = text name = "num1" id = "num1"> <br>
<input type = text name = "num2" id = "num2"> <br>
<input type = "submit">
</form> ```

Comment: How have you packaged this web application? How have you deployed this web application to a Servlet container?